# String execute as object property in php(laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to make dynamic object property from the sting.

```
$str = '{{$applications->' . str_replace( array('a.','b.','c.','d.'), '', $each_col_array[0]).'}}'
$str = "{{$applicants->applicant_name_en}}" //output
```

I used this `<?php eval($str) ?>` for view in blade but gives syntax error, unexpected in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
<?php $str = str_replace( array('a.','b.','c.','d.'), '', $each_col_array[0])?>
<p>{{$each_col_array[1]}}: <?php  echo $applicants->$str ?></p>
```